# Most efficient way to query in a data tree that does not have proper indexing

Tags: node.js, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, tree

Pardon me if the terminology of the title is wrong. Let me illustrate what I mean:

I have a data tree for a basic educational course. Every node holds 2 values(apart from children and parent data): ID and a bool value. I can not change the ID value since I am fetching it from an API so I can not form my data tree as a binary tree. That is what I mean by "does not have proper indexing".
BTW: ID is random.

[image]

As you can see, I am structuring my tree with a hierarchy. Courses are supersets of episodes and episodes are supersets of topics.

**My question:**

I want to gather some data from a specific topic node. I know it is a topic node and I know its id. How do I find that node to get some data out of it most efficiently?

When I researched about tree data structures, they usually index their nodes with some sort of rule (ex: binary trees), I am not sure I can do that since I want to preserve the hierarchy of data types. If there is a way that I can both keep some sort of indication of hierarchy and order my trees for many efficient queries. I am happy to do that. I don't want to brute force if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the usual Node class approach with a dictionary which you maintain at tree instance level.

For instance:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id, name, boolval):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name 
        self.boolval = boolval
        self.children = []
    
    def tolist(self):  # utility method for simple visualisation
        if not self.children:
            return [self.name]
        else:
            return [self.name, [child.tolist() for child in self.children]]

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = dict()  # this will map id to node
        self.root = None
    
    def append(self, id, name, boolval, parentid=""):
        node = Node(id, name, boolval)
        self.dict[id] = node
        if self.root:
            parent = self.get(parentid)
            parent.children.append(node)
        else:
            self.root = node
        
    def get(self, id):
        return self.dict[id]

    def tolist(self):
        if not self.root:
            return
        return self.root.tolist()


# demo use:
tree = Tree()
tree.append("ab12", "Tree", False)
tree.append("ab13", "Physics", False, "ab12")
tree.append("a4d5", "Math", False, "ab12")
tree.append("524d", "Section A", False, "a4d5")
# ...etc

print(tree.tolist())
```

If you need to know from a given node what its hierarchy is, then add parent references:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id, name, boolval):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name 
        self.boolval = boolval
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    def path(self):
        if self.parent:
            return self.parent.path() + [self.id]
        return [self.id] 

    def tolist(self):  # utility method for simple visualisation
        if not self.children:
            return [self.name]
        else:
            return [self.name, [child.tolist() for child in self.children]]

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = dict()  # this will map id to node
        self.root = None
    
    def append(self, id, name, boolval, parentid=""):
        node = Node(id, name, boolval)
        self.dict[id] = node
        if self.root:
            parent = self.get(parentid)
            parent.children.append(node)
            node.parent = parent
        else:
            self.root = node
        
    def get(self, id):
        return self.dict[id]

    def tolist(self):
        if not self.root:
            return
        return self.root.tolist()


# demo use:
tree = Tree()
tree.append("ab12", "Tree", False)
tree.append("ab13", "Physics", False, "ab12")
tree.append("a4d5", "Math", False, "ab12")
tree.append("524d", "Section A", False, "a4d5")
# ...etc

print(tree.tolist())
print(tree.get("524d").path())  # ['ab12', 'a4d5', '524d']
```

Comment: I think this is a way. Though, one question. Is it possible to give both dictionary and the tree the exact variable, not clones? What I mean is creating a one node object and appending its pointer to the tree and dictionary, as you do in c++. This way we won't duplicate data and since when node object is changed it will affect both of those data collections? Because your solution does not actually solve my issue since even if I reach the data of the node from the dictionary. I will still have to query through my tree to find 
 the hierarchy of my node

Comment: First, the node variables *are* references, so what you put in the dictionary is the same reference. There is no copy of the object, just of the reference, just as is the case in C++. For the other point: if you need to know the hierarchy, then you can add parent pointers in your data structure. Just add a `parent` member to the `Node` class and keep it updated.

Comment: Added some code to show how parent references allow to construct a path from the root to any given node.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. One little question is finding an entry inside a dictionary efficient, or in a map efficient. does dict["id"]  brute force through values. I am just trying to understand. I am a self-taught so writing efficient code is something I truly want to learn

Comment: It is efficient. A python dictionary is what is generally called a [hash table or hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table): it's reason for being is that it is efficient in lookup by key, insertion, and deletion by key.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to use a hash table structure when I am coding this on node.js

Comment: In nodejs you can use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or a plain object.